# Find logic expression for given truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I was given this truth table and I need to find a logical expression for the formula to give such a result (where there can be two or three 2-place connective expressions (e.g. $A \lor B$ counts as one but $\neg A$ does not count since only one variable is within it). Can anyone help me? I have been thinking for ages and I am not getting anywhere near the answer!

P   Q   R   (Formula)

T   T   T   F

T   T   F   T

T   F   T   F

T   F   F   T

F   T   T   T

F   T   F   F

F   F   T   F

F   F   F   F

Answer (score 4):

Look at each row in which $T$ is in the right-most column.

Then "and" all the truth-value assignments that yield that row true, and do the same for the remaining rows which evaluate to true:

P   Q   R   (Formula)

T   T   T   F

T   T   F   **T** $\leftarrow$

T   F   T   F

T   F   F   **T** $\leftarrow$

F   T   T   **T** $\leftarrow$

F   T   F   F

F   F   T   F

F   F   F   F

---

What we get is the proposition in *normal disjunctive form*:

$$(P\land Q \land \lnot R) \lor (P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)\tag{1}$$

Each of the disjuncts above represents a different row of the truth table (each one yielding true in the right-most column): Note that there are three possible truth-value assignments to the variables that make the expression true; we use "or" between the three clauses since all it takes is one of those clauses to be true in order for the proposition to be true.

$(1)$ no doubt can be simplified; I'll leave that to you. Give it a go, and follow up below if you get stuck.

Edit: $$\begin{align}(P\land Q \land \lnot R) \lor (P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)
&\equiv [(P \land \lnot R)\land(Q\lor \lnot Q)] \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)\\ \\
&\equiv (P\land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)
\end{align}$$

Comment: yes i got that at first! but i simply dunno how to simplify it!! can u please guide me through it!!! thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is $$(P \land Q \land \neg R) \lor (P \land \neg Q \land \neg R) \lor (\neg P \land Q \land R)$$

The above statement is the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) of the searched statement. You get it by looking at all cases, where the final statement should be true. Then you concatenate each input ($A$ if the variable $A$ is true in this case and $\neg A$ if $A$ is false in this case) with $\land$. All these statements are afterwards concatenated with $\lor$.